# How to change Binance server time using Python?

Tags: time, server, vpn, binance

### Question

How can I change the server time of Binance, one of the biggest cryptocurrency exchange, using the programming language Python?

### Details

1. I am using the python library **`[python-binance](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance)'** to interact with Binance.
2. When I typed the code below, you get the local time based on your location.

```
from binance.client import Client
from datetime import datetime

# client = Client('api_key' , 'api_secret')  # Binance API key

raw_server_time = client.get_server_time()
server_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(raw_server_time['serverTime']/1000.0)
server_time
```

Since I am in France, the result is as follows:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 23, 12, 49, 10, 13000)
```

3. Even though I am in France, **I would like to make Binance think that I am in the Eastern part of the USA (e.g. New York)**. So I have tried the requests library, supported in the python-binance library as below.

```
proxies = {
    'http': 'http://168.169.146.12:8080'
}

# in the Client instantiation
client = Client(api_key, api_secret, {'proxies': proxies})

# or on an individual call
client.get_all_orders(symbol='BTCUSDT', requests_params={'proxies': proxies})
```

But I get the following error message.

```
>>> BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-1021): Timestamp for this request was 1000ms ahead of the server's time.
```

You can find more detailed information about the code above in the **[documentation page](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#requests-settings)** of the python-binance library. The http server was found in the website [free-proxy.cz](http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/region/New%20York/all/speed). A screenshot of the list of New-York based proxies are also provided below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I got this error too, while writing python code in Microsoft Visual Code(**MVC**).
When i kept my Bot running, this also happens over time while bot was active. So i needed the Bot to alter my computer time. I found the following sollution:

#### How to adjust my computer time:

important to run program as 'Administrator', and have WindowsTime active.
*Search in 'services' for WindowsTime and make sure this is running/active. Auto-run on startup if needed*

At this line of code on startup of the Bot:

```
import os

os.system('w32tm/resync')
```

#### Keeping Bot active over time

After i synced the time at the start, i am monitoring error responses from binance for the TimeStamp error. When the timestamp message is found it will resync my computer time again.

```
 try:
    ###put for example buy code here###

 except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    substring = 'Timestamp for this request was 1000ms ahead of the server'
    if substring in e.message:
       os.system('w32tm/resync')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Windows 10, or Windows 11, do the following:

1. Start -> search date and time
2. Make sure you have set **Set time automatically** to **On**
3. In the opened window you have an option **Synchronize your clock**, and press **Sync now**.

I observed this problem sometimes after my PC goes to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import win32api

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
server_time = client.get_server_time()
gmtime=time.gmtime(int((server_time["serverTime"])/1000))
win32api.SetSystemTime(gmtime[0],gmtime[1],0,gmtime[2],gmtime[3],gmtime[4],gmtime[5],0) // Needed Administrator Permission
```

Answer (score -2):

For Windows, try this: https://steemit.com/crypto/@biyi/how-to-resolve-binance-s-timestamp-ahead-of-server-s-time-challenge
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
w32tm /resync